# sql server connection works for console project but not windows form project

Tags: c#, sql, api, windows-forms-designer

I am using console to write a class to handle a sql server link and another class to handle a data API. But If I use the same class in a windows form, neither of those classes works, they can not set up the connection.  It fails when I try to connect sql server database and also, can not setup the connection with the Data API at all.

What is different between building a C# console project and C# windows form project? How do I set up those connections? Is there any configuration I can change?

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=JF-T7K5-01;Initial Catalog=" + DataBaseName +";Integrated    Security=True;";
        Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the error message received when running the winform project

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you first check framework type. I have tried both console and form, connection works on both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the database right. But for that API, I found some interesting feature. There is a main object CQGCEL, if I put configure setting and request into one function, it is always fail. but if I put that into different function, and set them in different button event, that is right working. It seems the program only send all the request when this button event complete.

Comment: Actually, your question does not ask this. I see that you only asked why console and windows form application differs.